# Insert values manually into sqlite tables with code androidstudio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to add values to a table in SQLite android. all I can find on the internet is how to add values using button(by creating a user interface to add the values). 
But I want to do this manually with code and directly, is it possible and how? 
Thanks.

Below is the DATABASE I'm working on!

PS: the values are texts of 200 words at least for each column

DATABASEHELPER.JAVA

```
  public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME="URTsqlite.db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="Anatomy";
        public static final String COL1="OrganName";
        public static final String COL2="Overview";
        public static final String COL3="Externalfeatures";
        public static final String COL4="Internalfeatures";
        public static final String COL5="role";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL( " create table " +TABLE_NAME+"(OrganName PRIMARY KEY,Overview TEXT,Externalfeatures TEXT,Internalfeatures TEXT,role TEXT)");

        }

        @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData (String OrganName ,String Overview ,String Externalfeatures ,String Internalfeatures,String role)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1,OrganName);
        contentValues.put(COL2,Overview);
        contentValues.put(COL3,Externalfeatures);
        contentValues.put(COL4,Internalfeatures);
        contentValues.put(COL5,role);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible and how?

Yes it is. You simply call your `insertData` method with the values you want to add.

e.g. say you had an `Activity` and wanted to add a single row then you could have the following in the Activity's `onCreate` method :-

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseHelper myDB;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity_main);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    myDB.insertData("hammond","overview blah","external features blah","internal features blah","makes music");
    ......... other code
}
```

Thus everytime the activity's onCreate method is run an attempt will be made to add a row (however as OrganName is implicitly `UNQIUE`, as it's the `PRIMARY KEY`, then once added it will no longer be added again, the conflict (duplicate) will be caught by the SQLiteDatabase `insert` method and thus allow processing to continue).

Saying that typically a pre-existing (externally created) database would be supplied as an asset, this being copied when the App is first run after it is installed.

Comment: Thanks, what i did is i've created an external sqlite database and used it through SQLite asset helper , but i've encountered a slight problem as described here, ((i'm sure the solution is easy but i can't figure out what is as i m new to android), thanks for the effort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584512/display-header-only-when-chlid-is-not-null-using-expandablelistview-android-stud