# Guide to use a large sqlite propulated database

Tags: android, sqlite

I know this kind questions has been around a lot (most of them with no valid answer), and getting through the answers i didn't find what i'm searching for which is:

1. if i want to use pictures in my database (insertion with sqlite browser), is there any specification(format,size) or limite? so they would work fine when i retrieve them in android. (PS: i have almost 100 JPEG pictures, each has approximately 1-2 Mo size , which count in total 150Mo just for pictures)
2. what's the size limit of database that can be inserted in android? ( i've read about inserting database in external file or something like that(because APK shouldn't be more than 50Mo), can you show me how?

why i'm asking those questions? because i have used a JPEG picture with 7Mb in my database and the app stopped..so i need to know how to use correctly pictures and manage size of database
Thanks

```
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class Database {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "URTs.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "OrganAnatomy";
    public static final String DATABASE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String DATABASE_GROUP_1 = "Larynx_features";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_1 = "Larynx";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_2 = "pictures";    

    private final Context mContext;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public Database(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void open() {
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mDB = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }    

    public void close() {
        if (mDatabaseHelper != null) mDatabaseHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getDatabase() {
        String whereclause = DATABASE_CHILD_1 + " IS NOT NULL";
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, whereclause, null, null, null, DATABASE_ID);
    }    

    public Cursor getID(long rowID) {
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, "_id" + " = "
                + rowID , null, null, null, null);    
    }    

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {    
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);    
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With regard to the 50Mb (now 100Mb) APK size you can find out about APK Expansion files at [APK Expansion Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files), which includes :-

> Each time you upload an APK using the Google Play Console, you have
> the option to add one or two expansion files to the APK. Each file can
> be up to 2GB and it can be any format you choose, but we recommend you
> use a compressed file to conserve bandwidth during the download.
> Conceptually, each expansion file plays a different role:
>
> The main expansion file is the primary expansion file for additional
> resources required by your application. The patch expansion file is
> optional and intended for small updates to the main expansion file.
> While you can use the two expansion files any way you wish, we
> recommend that the main expansion file deliver the primary assets and
> should rarely if ever updated; the patch expansion file should be
> smaller and serve as a “patch carrier,” getting updated with each
> major release or as necessary.
>
> However, even if your application update requires only a new patch
> expansion file, you still must upload a new APK with an updated
> versionCode in the manifest. (The Play Console does not allow you to
> upload an expansion file to an existing APK.)

With regard to storing images in SQLite, for images that are larger than around 100k, you should store the images as files and store the path to the image in the database.

There is a restriction, not with SQLite (see below), but with the maximum size of an Android Cursor Window, which is 2Mb, that restricts or can have a noticeable detrimental impact when retrieving large blobs. Hence why your 7Mb image could be stored but not retrieved.

For SQLite there is a limit as per :-

> Maximum length of a string or BLOB
>
> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined
> by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this
> macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can
> raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option
> like this:
>
> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789 The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647. And some
> built-in functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In
> security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the
> maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower
> the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a
> few million if that is possible.
>
> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete
> content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So
> the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of
> bytes in a row.
>
> The maximum string or BLOB length can be lowered at run-time using the
> sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size) interface.

[Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

**Example App**

This App Stores Smaller Images in DB but stores the path for larger images (size to determine which based upon `public static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 100 * 1024;`)

The DatabaseHelper **DBHelper.java** :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "images.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    // The maximum size of an image that should be stored 100K
    public static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 100 * 1024;

    public static final String TB_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String COL_IMAGE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_IMAGE_PATH = "image_path";
    public static final String COL_IMAGE_NAME = "image_name";
    public static final String COl_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION = "image_description";
    public static final String COL_IMAGE_SIZE = "image_size";
    public static final String COL_IMAGE_IMAGE = "image";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    /**
     * Construct DBHelper, note that it will open the database and
     * thus create it if it doesn't exist
     * @param context   a context from the invoking activity
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * Create the table(s)
     * @param db
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_IMAGE +
                "(" +
                COL_IMAGE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +
                COL_IMAGE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
                COL_IMAGE_SIZE + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_IMAGE_IMAGE + " BLOB DEFAULT x'00'" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor with all the rows from the image table
     * @return  The Cursor
     */
    public Cursor getImageList() {
        return mDB.query(TB_IMAGE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }


    /**
     * Store an image row in the image table, noting that is the image
     *  size is small than the max size that the image will be stored as a blob
     *  otherwise a blob of 1 byte is stored due to the default value.
     * @param path          the path to the image
     * @param description   a description for the image
     * @return              the id (rowid) of the row
     */
    public long addImageFromPath(String path, String description) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        File f = new File(path);
        InputStream is;

        // If the file doesn't exist don't store a row
        if (!f.exists()) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Always store the name, description, path and size
        cv.put(COL_IMAGE_NAME,f.getName());
        cv.put(COl_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION,description);
        cv.put(COL_IMAGE_SIZE,f.length());
        cv.put(COL_IMAGE_PATH,f.getAbsolutePath());

        // If the size is less than the max then get the filestream
        // and convert to a byte[].
        // Note if larger then the max file size the default x'00' blob
        // will be applied
        if (f.length() < MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(f);
                is.read(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            }
            cv.put(COL_IMAGE_IMAGE,buffer);
        }
        // Do the insert
        return mDB.insert(TB_IMAGE,null,cv);
    }

    /**
     * get the image as a bitmap from the DB if stored, otherwise get it from
     * the file, according to the id.
     * @param id    the id of the row in the image table
     * @return      the bitmap to be returned (note may be empty bitmap)
     */
    public Bitmap getImage(long id) {
        byte[] ba = new byte[0];

        // If the image is stored in the DB then extract and return the bitmap
        if (isStoredAsImage(id)) {
            return getImageAsBitMap(id);
        }
        // If not then get the respective row from the DB
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_IMAGE,
                null,
                COL_IMAGE_ID+"=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        // Prepare to convert the path to a file
        String path = ""; //<<<< default to  empty path
        File f = new File(path); //<<< default to empty file
        // If a valid row was found get the path and File from the row
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            path = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_IMAGE_PATH));
            f = new File(path);
        }
        // done with the cursor so close it
        csr.close();

        // If the file exists then return the Bitmap
        if (f.exists()) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        // return an empty bitmap
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba,0,ba.length);
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if an image is stored in the DB,
     *  note assumes anything less than 8 bytes isn't an image
     * @param id    the id of the row in the image table
     * @return      true if like an image is stored, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean isStoredAsImage(long id) {
        boolean rv = true;
        byte[] ba = new byte[0];

        // Get the respective row from the image table
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_IMAGE,
                null,
                COL_IMAGE_ID+"=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        // If a row was found get the blob into byte array ba
        // if not then ready to return false
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            ba = csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_IMAGE_IMAGE));
        } else {
            rv = false;
        }
        // If the byte array ba is less then 8 bytes then ready to return false
        if (ba == null || ba.length < 8) {
            rv =  false;
        }
        // done with the Cursor so close it
        csr.close();
        // return the result
        return rv;
    }

    /**
     * get the image (assumes isStoredAsImage is used prior to invocation)
     * @param id    the id of the respective row
     * @return      the bitmap (may be 0 length)
     */
    private Bitmap getImageAsBitMap(long id) {
        byte[] ba = new byte[0];
        Bitmap bmp;
        Cursor csr =mDB.query(
                TB_IMAGE,
                null,
                COL_IMAGE_ID+"=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            ba = csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_IMAGE_IMAGE));
        }
        csr.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba,0,ba.length);
    }
}
```

The MainActivity **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String IMAGE_STORE_PATH;
    public static final String IMAGES_DIRECTORY = "images";
    private static File images_file;

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    ListView mListView01, mListView02;
    ArrayList<String> mImages;
    CursorAdapter mCsrAdapter;
    Cursor mCsr;
    ImageView mImageView;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // get the View/Viewgroup IDs
        mListView01 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview001); // File List
        mListView02 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview002); // DB List
        mImageView = this.findViewById(R.id.imageview001); // Image display

        // get an instance of the DBHelper
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        // Copy images from raw folder to data/data/<package>/Files/images
        // Also store all the images in the Database (or not depedning upon size)
        getImagesFile(this);
        if (getImagesCount() < 1) {
            loadRawImages();
            storeImagesToDB();
        }
        // Setup the two ListViews to display image name lists
        displayList();
        displayListFromDB();

        // setup the file list so that when an item is clicked the image is displayed
        mListView01.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String imagename = mListView01.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                displayImage(imagename);
            }
        });

        // setup the DB list so that when an item is clicked the image is displayed
        mListView02.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                displayDBImage(l);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Store the images in the images folder to the DB giving then a calculated description
     * e.g. image1, image2 .....
     */
    private void storeImagesToDB() {
        File f = getImagesFile(this);
        File[] images = f.listFiles();
        int imagecounter = 1;
        for (File img: images) {
            mDBHlpr.addImageFromPath(img.getPath(),"image" + String.valueOf(imagecounter++));
        }
    }

    /**
     * return the directory/folder where the images are stored as a File
     * @param context   a valid context
     * @return          the number of images
     */
    public static File getImagesFile(Context context) {
        if (images_file == null) {
            images_file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + IMAGES_DIRECTORY);
            if (!images_file.exists()) {
                images_file.mkdirs();
            }
        }
        return images_file;
    }

    /**
     * get the number of images
     * @return the number of images
     */
    public static long getImagesCount() {
        File[] files = images_file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isFile();
            }
        });
        return (long) files.length;
    }

    /**
     * Setup/refresh the list of images according to the images folder
     * (left ListView)
     */
    private void displayList() {
        if (mImages == null) {
            mImages = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            mImages.clear();
        }
        mImages.addAll(Arrays.asList(images_file.list()));
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mImages);
            mListView01.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the image view according to the file
     * @param imageName the name of the image (as per the ListView)
     */
    private void displayImage(String imageName) {
        File img = new File(images_file.getPath() + File.separator + imageName);
        if (img.exists()) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath());
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the image view according to the image stored/referred to by the DB
     * @param id    the id of the respective row in the image table
     */
    private void displayDBImage(long id) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mDBHlpr.getImage(id));
    }

    /**
     * Setup/refresh the list of images as obtained from the DB (right listview)
     */
    private void displayListFromDB() {
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getImageList();
        if (mCsrAdapter == null) {
            mCsrAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mCsr,
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COL_IMAGE_NAME,DBHelper.COL_IMAGE_PATH},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            mListView02.setAdapter(mCsrAdapter);
        } else {
            mCsrAdapter.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load (copy from raw folder to images folder) all images
     */
    private void loadRawImages() {
        Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
        int resourceID = 0;
        String resourceName;
        for (Field fld: fields) {
            resourceName = fld.getName();
            try {
                resourceID = fld.getInt(fld);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("RAW FLDINFO","name=" + fld.getName() + " ID=" + String.valueOf(resourceID));
            copyResourceImageToImages(resourceID,resourceName, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Copy an image from the raw directory (app/src/main/res/raw directory) to
     *  the App's data/data/files/images folder
     * @param resourceID        ID of the resource
     * @param resourceName      name of the resource (file name less extension)
     * @param throw_exception   true if an exception should be thrown
     */
    private void copyResourceImageToImages(int resourceID, String resourceName, boolean throw_exception) {
        String tag = "CPYRSRCTOIMAGES";
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
        File of = new File(images_file.getPath() + File.separator + resourceName + ".jpg");
        Log.d(tag,"Initiating Copy of File " + of.getName());
        int buffer_size = 1024 * 4;
        int length_to_copy = buffer_size;
        int bytesread = 0;
        long bytescopied = 0;
        OutputStream os;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        if (!of.exists()) {
            try {
                of.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(tag,"Error Creating File " + of.getName());
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (throw_exception) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error Creating Output File" + of.getName());
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(of);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag,"Error Creating OutputStream for File " + of.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (throw_exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error Creating OutputStream for File " + of.getName());
            }
            return;
        }
        if (os == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("OutputStream not initialised.");
        }
        try {
            while ((bytesread = is.read(buffer)) > 0 ){
                try {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    String msg = "Error Writing to Output File " + of.getName() + " Bytes Copied = " + bytescopied;
                    Log.d(tag, msg);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (throw_exception) {
                        os.close();
                        of.delete();
                        throw new RuntimeException(msg);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                    of.delete();
                    return;
                }
                bytescopied = bytescopied + bytesread;
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "Error reading Input File " + resourceName + " Bytes Copied = " + bytescopied;
            Log.d(tag,"Error Reading Input File " + resourceName);
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (throw_exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(msg);
            }
            try {
                is.close();
                os.close();
                of.delete();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.d(tag,"File " + of.getName() +" Copied - Bytes Successfully Copied = " + bytescopied);
        try {
            os.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Layout for MainActivity **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/listview001"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview001"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#FFFFAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scrollview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/listview002"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview002"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#FFAAAAFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scrollview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/listview001"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

    </ListView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/listview001"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listview001">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview001"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFAAFFAA"
            android:contentDescription="A Picture"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note Images are stored in the res/raw folder e.g. :-

[image]

The Database (from id 20) looks like (highlighted is the one image under 100k that is stored in the DB (note file left on disk but could be deleted to save space if wanted)) :-

[image]

#### App when first started (no image show) :-

[image]

#### Click on Image dsc0055.jpg (either ListView works)

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, helpful as always! ..just two stupid questions: 1/ if i managed to reduce the size of each picture to less than 100k ..(is it okey then to store them in sqlite database , the 100 of them)? ..2/what do you mean by store the image in file and store the path to the image in database? (do you mean create a file in desktop or the app folder..and how they will be displayed as pictures in the app if they're just paths to a floder) could you explain more because i think this is maybe this is the solution to my problem ..Sorry of bothering you

Comment: Yes, the 100k is based upon efficiency as per [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html). Store as a file means as a jpg/png in say the res/raw folder or perhaps in the assets folder. Will, drop in code to the answer for an example App that stores small images in DB as blob or for larger images as a path.

Comment: Okey got you for the first answer. but for the second still can't figure out how to do it. what did you meant by 'will,drop in code" ..are you gonna post an answer or should i provide you with my code ..sorry again

Comment: @ErrahbiZouhair the code is there now, plus screen shot of storing images. Will add screen shot of database contents shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort ..i really do appreciate it ..but i'm using an expendable list view and simplecursortreeadapter ..as you can see here : this is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584512/display-header-only-when-chlid-is-not-null-using-expandablelistview-android-stud (for Main aticivty Java , i have added a view binder as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620110/trouble-with-viewbinder-simplecursortreeadapter-unable-to-convert-string-to-blo)

Comment: i'm new to android , and i know its hard for you to explain that much ..so i'll tell you what i did understand and correct me if i'm wrong
Starting from the code in my previous comments (I have only 2 classes: Database.java(in which i imported an external sqlite database which have pictures and texts) and maintactivity.java)

1-i'll create a new directory in assets and i'll call it "images"
2-i'll add a new class DBHelper and fill it with what you have ..(But i have already a database.java that use external database? ..or should i do it anyway?)

Comment: 3-for main activity.java , i didn't understand nothing, there is too much code for a beginner for me to know where to add it in my mainactivity.java ..could you based on my mainactivity.java? (you'll find it in the link the previous comment..Thanks again for the appreciated effort

Comment: You would need to adapt the code or look at it and get to understand it. Perhaps you could create a new project using  the code (copy some images into the res/raw folder ) and run it and play with it to get to understand the code and then use it in your main App.

Comment: Yeah okey , just Yes/NO.. should i create a new DBhelper.java and keep it along my database.java? thanks

Comment: No amend existing database.java, perhaps starting with amending the pre-existing DB to incorporate new columns e.g. **image_path**.